# How can I get proportion of total value in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to get every nationality proportion (percent) of total value_eur.

I've tried this so far:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT sum(value_eur), nationality
    FROM Fifadf
    GROUP by nationality
)
SELECT nationality, value_eur, 1. * value_eur / sum(value_eur) over (partition by nationality) as prop 
FROM CTE
```

It gives me an error. [excel table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ik2s.png)

Here's a sample input table:

| Nationality | Value |
| --- | --- |
| n1 | 1000 |
| n1 | 2000 |
| n2 | 2000 |
| n3 | 3000 |
| n3 | 3000 |

Expected Output:

| Nationality | Value | Prop |
| --- | --- | --- |
| n1 | 3000 | 27,27% |
| n2 | 2000 | 18,18% |
| n3 | 6000 | 54,54% |

Comment: You are selecting `value_eur` from the `CTE`, but it's not there!!

Comment: Include sample data as text rather then image.

Comment: You don't need to use the `CTE`, the second query is enough to get what you want.https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/x4gB3NF4crthLeMC8VVCeQ/0

Comment: @Ahmed Thanks for your answer, however when I fill this the countries won't be grouped by and you will see several times argentina in the list.

When I use group by, the Prop will be 1

Comment: Can you post a sample of the expected result?

Comment: @Ahmed Yes, I put a new answer in the post.

Comment: Don't vandalize your own post. Instead if Ahmed solution represents the one that worked for you, give credit to him for the time he spent and accept it as the answer of this post. Also carry out this operation for all the questions you've asked till now. @Kaffo

Answer (score 2):

Try with this one:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT nationality,
           SUM(value_eur) AS Value_
    FROM Fifadf
    GROUP BY nationality
)
SELECT nationality,
       Value_,
       Value_ / SUM(Value_) OVER() AS Prop
FROM cte
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rPEoqaDkjErfk66daKNxqR/0).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
select distinct nationality,
sum(value_eur) over (partition by nationality) as Value ,
1.0 * sum(value_eur) over (partition by nationality)/(select sum(value_eur) from MyData) as Prob
from MyData
```

See a demo from [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/x4gB3NF4crthLeMC8VVCeQ/1).

Comment: this has no group so will return 2 rows of n1

Comment: @AIMINPAN, I used `distinct` to avoid duplicate rows.